# Find the angles formed by a line with the coordinate axes

Tags: analytic-geometry

Determine the angles formed by the given line with the coordinates axis
$ (D): { x-2y-5=0}
 / {x-3z+8=0 } $ ( this is a system of 2 equations, I don't know how to format it properly )

I know the directionals are ( 1, -2 , 0) and (1,0,-3) but I don't really know how to continue it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**just a hint to finish**

The line $(D) $ can be defined by following parametric equations

$$x=x $$
$$y=(x-5)/2$$
$$z=(x+8)/3$$

thus the vector director of $(D) $
is
$$\vec {u}=(1,1/2,1/3) $$ or
$$(6,3,2) $$

use
$$\cos (\vec{u},\vec{v})=\frac {\vec {u}\cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec {u}||||\vec {v}||} $$

Answer (score 0):

The system of equations describes the line as the intersection of two planes. It must therefore be perpendicular to the normals of *both* planes, so its direction vector is $(1,0,-3)\times(1,-2,0)=(6,-3,2)$. The corresponding unit vector is $\left(\frac67,-\frac37,\frac27\right)$. Since $v\cdot w = \|v\|\,\|w\|\cos\theta$, the components of this vector are the cosines of the angles it makes with the coordinate axes.